# MySQL LEFT JOIN RAND() - Weird behaviour ? or am i doing something wrong?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm almost sure i am doing something wrong, but i cannot figure out what exactly.

The query runs fine a few times, and sometimes returns an empty `aff_affiliatelink`, for no reason.
If i remove the RAND() from the first JOIN, everything works fine, but, i need a random affiliate...
any idea on what might be causing this ?

**EDIT**: Just noticed something, the game_software for the failed `aff_affiliatelink` is always "2". Don't know if it has any connection, but it might be useful in understanding what is wrong.

Here is my query:

```
   SELECT game_software,
          aff_affiliatelink
     FROM games g     
LEFT JOIN (SELECT asoft_affiliateid,asoft_softwareid 
             FROM affiliates_software 
         ORDER BY RAND() ) aff_soft ON aff_soft.asoft_softwareid =g.game_software    
LEFT JOIN (SELECT aff_id, 
                  aff_affiliatelink,
                  aff_description,
                  aff_bonus,
                  aff_title,
                  aff_image,
                  aff_imagealt,
                  aff_banner,
                  aff_banneralt 
             FROM affiliates 
            WHERE aff_isactive = 1) aff ON aff_id=aff_soft.asoft_affiliateid     
 GROUP BY game_id 
 ORDER BY game_releasedate DESC
```

**EDIT** : After changing the second LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN,
It seems to work, but im not sure that is the correct way of doing it....
if anyone has another idea, please tell, i will leave this question open until i will get a decent answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some more test the solution was to change the second left join to an inner join.
thanks for the help.

```
SELECT game_id,gtype_imagefolder,game_isactive,game_title,game_description,game_image,game_imagealt,game_content,game_alias,game_software,game_flashlink,game_metatitle,game_metakeywords,game_metadescription,game_h1title,game_h1content,game_h2title,game_h2content,aff_affiliatelink,aff_description,aff_bonus,aff_id,aff_title,aff_image,aff_imagealt,aff_banner,aff_banneralt  
FROM games g 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT asoft_affiliateid,asoft_softwareid 
      FROM affiliates_software 
      ORDER BY RAND() ) aff_soft 
ON g.game_software=aff_soft.asoft_softwareid 
INNER JOIN (SELECT aff_id,aff_affiliatelink,aff_description,aff_bonus,aff_title,aff_image,aff_imagealt,aff_banner,aff_banneralt 
            FROM affiliates 
            WHERE aff_isactive=1) aff 
ON aff_id=asoft_affiliateid 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT gtype_imagefolder,gtype_id FROM games_type) gt ON game_type=gtype_id 
WHERE game_type=1 

GROUP BY game_id ORDER BY game_releasedate DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're re-ordering the query later.  If you're trying to get a single item from a random affiliate, you should add a `LIMIT 1` after the `ORDER BY RAND()`.  Otherwise the order does nothing but slow down your query since it'll be overridden later by the outer order.

Oh, and you should check out [this blog post](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) about `ORDER BY RAND()`...

Comment: @Rephael: ORDER BY RAND() may not affect the speed - but it does not give you any benefit where it is placed.

Comment: well, it seems that it is.
since if i remove it, i get the same affiliate each time.
while its there, i get a diffrent affiliate each time.
which is what i need.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  game_software, aff_affiliatelink
FROM    (
        SELECT  game_software, game_releasedate
                (
                SELECT  asoft_affiliateid
                FROM    affiliates_software afs
                WHERE   afs.afost_softwareid = g.game_software
                ORDER BY
                        RAND()
                LIMIT 1
                ) AS asoft_affiliateid
        FROM    games g
        ) asd
LEFT JOIN
        affiliates a
ON      a.aff_id = asd.asoft_affiliateid
        AND a.aff_isactive = 1
ORDER BY
        game_releasedate DESC
```

Comment: Hi quassnoi, i will try this and report back.

Comment: @Rephael: for this kind of query, it's better to keep the list of affiliates as a comma-separated list in `games`. This will speed it up.

Comment: well, after testing this solution, i am sorry to say, the same happens.
if you run the code a few times, it returns an empty data for affiliate for some reaason.

Comment: i was using comma seperated values at start.
the code i posted is just a breakdown of the problem.
i am taking a lot more fields out, some from the affiliates table and some from the software.

Comment: @Rephael: this means that the game in question has no active affiliates associated with it. If you don't want it to be returned, replace `LEFT JOIN` with an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Well if you check the the edits in the posts, that what i did.

Comment: @Rephael: ok then. However, using `GROUP BY` is not a correct method of doing it: this query may break if there are enough affiliates to software links for the `GROUP BY` not to be done completely in memory.

Comment: could you explain how come it will break ?
i didnt understood that.

Comment: @Rephael: by `SQL` standard, your query wouldn't run at all, since you are have `aff_affiliatelink` in `SELECT` list, which is neither grouped by nor aggregated. `MySQL` extends the standard and allows selecting it, but does not guarantee which one from the group will be selected. Theoretically, any affiliate can be selected for each game in this query. Practically (only in current implementation), it will be the first one found when scanning the table, but only unless the join is made in single pass.

Comment: well, that is exactly what i wanted.
any affiliate (random) to be attached to a game.
since the RAND is inside the first join,
it returns a random affiliate, which is what i need. i dont understand why you think it will return the first found, since clearly it dosent.

Comment: @Rephael: just don't be surprised when your query starts returning the same affiliate for some games as the number of links grows.